After successful SSH connections can not type anything
I am using Ubuntu and after my successful login in my SSH I can not type anything. When I reboot my computer and open a Terminal, I run the command ssh root@****. I receive a password prompt where I enter the correct password, showing me the welcome message . After that instead of receiving the prompt, I have a blinking cursor on a new line and I can not type anything.Yesterday everything was working well and now I am facing this problem.
In the image I have deleted the files with the pass and the shh root login(safety reasons).
this is the problem that I am facing
Here are my SSHD logs
May 9 11:04:44 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New seat seat0.
May 9 11:04:49 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD useradd[1042]: new user: name=lxd, UID=998, GID=100, home=/var/snap/lxd/common/lxd, shell=/bin/false, from=none
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1324]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New session 1 of user
May 9 11:04:53 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1568]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[300]: New session 3 of user root.
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:04:54 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[1637]: ROOT LOGIN on '/dev/pts/3'
May 9 11:17:01 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD CRON[1890]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:17:01 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD CRON[1890]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:23:22 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
May 9 11:23:22 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:23:50 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:23:57 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl restart sshd
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:25:21 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:25:41 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl list-unit-files
May 9 11:25:41 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:25:42 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl start ssh.service
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:26:00 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: user: TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/systemctl status ssh.service
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 9 11:26:17 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 9 11:41:35 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[296]: New seat seat0.
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[549]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd-logind[296]: New session 1 of user user
May 9 11:41:39 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user by (uid=0)
May 9 11:41:44 DESKTOP-KTUFCTD login[782]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)


Post the verbose server logs and verbose client logs at the time of the client connecting.

I was speaking of SSHD logs not your auth logs, and an the information you should be contained in the question not an answer, answers are a way to reply to user.

I have edited the question. Please check

Create a new user on the server, determine if that works, if it does then it’s something with root. I suspect just a shell problem. The next step would be to su to root as that new user “su - root” specifically

I will try that. Thank you.

I have tried with another user and the problem is still there. I don't what else to do . Please help

I assume you have tried rebooting the machine?

The log indicates you've successfully authenticated and a session is starting up.
Just a blinking cursor instead of a prompt in that situation would mean that one of the scripts executed at session startup never ends. Maybe you (or another system administrator, if applicable) have a mistyped command in one of those scripts?
Since the problem appears on another user too, it must be located within the system-wide session startup scripts, e.g. /etc/bash.bashrc or /etc/profile (and/or any files in /etc/profile.d directory, if it exists).
You might want to temporarily add a set -x command to the beginning of /etc/profile. It will cause the shell to display every command before executing it, in its final form after all expansions are done.
The target system seems to be using CloudPanel, indicating that it is probably something you've rented from a cloud or other hosting provider. So it is definitely accessible from the internet. In that situation, allowing root logins by password is a bad idea: if the root password can be guessed using a dictionary, an intruder could gain control of the system quickly after the system is set up. If you haven't been using a very strong, unguessable password, you can probably assume the target system has been hacked and rootkitted to prevent you from regaining root access to it without a reinstall. If you must allow root logins, you should set up SSH key authentication for that purpose.
(Scanning the IP address spaces of hosting operators for new, possibly poorly-configured virtual systems is probably an easy way to find systems vulnerable to hacking.)

I have tries everything but the problem still persists. At the end I believe I have corrupted files and I really don't know what to do.
